# Can not archive NSDictionary with NSKeyedArchiver - method does not get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nskeyedarchiver, archiving

I've recently gotten into a problem where for some reason I simply can not get Xcode to call the `archiveRootObject:toFile:` method. I think it has something to do with what the `NSMutableDictionary` contains, because I've been able to replace the `NSMutableDictionary` I actually want to say with a super simple dictionary that saved just fine, like so:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"lea": @"marolt",
                      };
```

What I'm trying to do is archive three things:

- NSMutableArray *events
- NSMutableArray *allDates
- NSDictionary *eventsDictionary

Here's the code to archive:

```
self.eventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:events];
self.eventsDictionary = eventsDictionary;
self.allDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:allDates];

[self.eventTableView reloadData];
[tumblrHUD hide];

[[PECache sharedCacheModel] archiveObject:self.eventsArray toFileName:@"CachedEvents"];
[[PECache sharedCacheModel] archiveObject:self.allDates toFileName:@"CachedAllDates"];
[[PECache sharedCacheModel] archiveObject:self.eventsDictionary toFileName:@"CachedEventsDict"];
```

Let me also mention that before archiving, none of the objects I'm trying to archive is null. They're all as they should be. If it helps, here's what the objects contain before archiving (for convenience's sake, I'm currently trying with 1 object only).

```
events:
```

> " {\n    Candidate = \"Chris Christie\";\n    City = Hampton;\n    Date = \"2015-06-18\";\n    Event = \"Town Hall Meeting\";\n    EventType = 1;\n    Price = 0;\n    RSVP = 1;\n    State = \"New Hampshire\";\n    Time = \"05:00 PM\";\n    Venue = \"Galley Hatch Restaurant\";\n    Zone = ET;\n}"

```
allDates:
```

> "2015-06-18"

```
eventsDictionary:
```

> "2015-06-18" =     (
>           " {\n    RSVP = 1;\n    candidate = \"\";\n    candidateName = \"Chris Christie\";\n    cityString = Hampton;\n    costNum = 0;\n    dateString = \"2015-06-18\";\n    event = \"Town Hall Meeting\";\n    eventType = 1;\n    idNum = F5WUpDX5Ju;\n    isGoing = 0;\n    startDate = \"2015-06-18 21:00:00 +0000\";\n    startTimeString = \"05:00 PM\";\n    stateString = \"New Hampshire\";\n    timeZone = ET;\n    venue = \"Galley Hatch Restaurant\";\n}"
>       );

I have a `Cache` class where I've implemented these methods:

```
- (void) archiveObject:(id)object toFileName:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cacheDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *filePath = [cacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:object toFile:filePath];
}

- (id) loadArchivedObjectWithFileName:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cacheDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *filePath = [cacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    id cachedObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];

    return cachedObject;
}
```

So, I'm at a loss right now. Please help?

Comment: You do not seem to check the return code from `archiveRootObject`. It returns false if something goes wrong. Most likely one of the objects in the hierarchy does not support the `NSCoding` protocol? Are you using any of your own/other classes in the dictionaries?

Comment: When I've NSLog-ed the method's return it returned YES for the first two, and nothing for the dictionary. I think I figured it out after doing some digging, though - yes, I'm using some custom objects in the dictionary, so it seems like it isn't supporting the NSCoding protocol. My bad! Thanks for the help (:

Comment: Just implement NSCoding in your classes and you will be fine. Its pretty simple to do.

Comment: It all works now! Thanks a bunch!